# Change privileges based on the installation folder

Tags: windows, winforms, installation, manifest, uac

I have a problem with a windows form.
I have created a setup project for this.
When I install my application in `c:\program files` folder, because UAC, my application when I made double click doesn't run.
So, i install in `C:\` folder and it works.
If I want that work in `C:\program files` I need to create and associate a manifest with

```
requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"
```

or

```
requestedExecutionLevel  level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false"
```

but in this manner each time that I open my appplication, it shows the windows with "unknown publisher..." and I need to click OK.

I'd like that when application is installed in a folder where UAC works, I must use manifest with the privileges as before, but if my installation folder is like `C:\` (UAC doesn't work) I don't want windows with "unknown publisher.."; in this case I need that work with embed manifest with default setting.

Comment: The underlying problem is that your application is doing something it isn't supposed to, most likely writing into the folder that it is installed in.  If you can identify and fix this problem, the application shouldn't need a manifest at all.  Process Monitor (available from Microsoft's web site) can often be useful in identifying this sort of problem.

Answer (score 2):

The `requireAdministrator` level is the one that you want to put in your setup program's manifest. This will enable you to install the application *anywhere* on the disk, whether in the Program Files folder or in the root directory (not sure why you'd want to do this), since an Administrator will have read/write access to all of those locations.

However, note that you want to add this to the application manifest for the ***setup program***, not your application. You only need these extra privileges *during installation*, not during the normal execution of your application. So you will only be prompted when running the setup wizard, not each time you launch the application. Once it's installed, users don't need read/write access to the application directory—just read-only access.

You will still see the "Unknown Publisher" on the UAC dialog, though. To fix that, you have to obtain an Authenticode certificate and use that to sign your executable. You can purchase one of these from someone like [Comodo](http://www.instantssl.com/code-signing/), [Symantec](https://www.symantec.com/code-signing) (formerly Verisign), or [Go Daddy](http://www.godaddy.com/ssl/code-signing-certificate.aspx). See [this article](http://www.wintellect.com/blogs/jrobbins/code-signing-it-s-cheaper-and-easier-than-you-thought) for more information on code signing. I highly recommend signing your executables if you intend them for general distribution. But if you don't want to, or can't afford it (say, it's only a hobby project), then it doesn't hurt anything—the user will just have to accept that it's from an unknown publisher.

Finally, it is worth mentioning that Windows has a special compatibility behavior that kicks in for setup applications named "setup.exe". These are automatically run with Administrative privileges, prompting for UAC elevation if necessary. So you should be able to get it to work even without adding this information to the manifest, but you should still do it anyway.

Comment: Your first paragraph is wrong. The default ACLs set by Windows allow all users to create folders in the root of `C:` but not in `C:\Program Files`. It is not a misconfiguration.

Comment: Really, @Andrew? That has not been my experience. Oh well, I don't have a clean system set up to verify it, so I'll have to go with you on this.

Comment: Yes, I've checked. It does seem odd, but it's definitely an intentional act by Microsoft (my guess is for compatibility with pre-NT apps that expect to be able to create items in the root).

Comment: That isn't a very good reason… Lots of pre-NT apps expected to be able to create items in the Windows directory, but let's hope that isn't public read/write. From what I can find online (and it's surprisingly difficult to search for), it appears that regular users can create items on the root directory, but they do *not* inherit ownership of those items.

Comment: I can confirm that the default ACLs on the system drive give "Authenticated Users" the access to add directories (but not files) on the root folder.  The creator of a directory should be given ownership as usual, I'd be very surprised if that had been special-cased, and the inherited permissions for the new folder include Modify access for "Authenticated Users".  The creator is *not* directly included in the inherited permissions, and in particular does not have Full access - so perhaps some people have confused that with not having ownership.